# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is not able to ignore the properties file even ignoreResourceNotFound=true

Tags: spring

**applicationContext.xml**

```
  <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="location" value="file:/#{contextParameters.emsPropLocation}"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- TIBCO Connection Factory Bean -->
  <bean id="tibcoConnectionFactory" class="com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory" lazy-init="true">
    <constructor-arg value="${emsServerURL}"/>
    <property name="userName" value="${emsUserName}"/>
    <property name="userPassword" value="${emsPassword}"/>
    <property name="connAttemptCount" value="${connAttemptCount}"/>
    <property name="connAttemptDelay" value="${connAttemptDelay}"/>
    <property name="connAttemptTimeout" value="${connAttemptTimeout}"/>
    <property name="reconnAttemptCount" value="${reconnAttemptCount}"/>
    <property name="reconnAttemptDelay" value="${reconnAttemptDelay}"/>
    <property name="reconnAttemptTimeout" value="${reconnAttemptTimeout}"/>
  </bean>
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>emsPropLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>D:/nsserver/config/EMSServerConf.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If EMSServerConf.properties file doesn't exist at specified location, "org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener" listener is not able load applicationContext.xml file properly. Although ignoreResourceNotFound property is set to "**true**".

Actually, I want to make this properties file optional.

**ERROR at tomcat server**

Dec 1, 2011 6:08:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Dec 1, 2011 6:08:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/upload] startup failed due to previous errors

I stuck badly... :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we load "org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" bean with lazy-init="true"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337652/can-we-load-org-springframework-beans-factory-config-propertyplaceholderconfigu)

Comment: `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders`

Comment: I tried to set the ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders=true but it didn't worked.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is likely the "#" in your location ( `<property name="location" value="file:/#{contextParameters.emsPropLocation}"/>`). Shouldn't it be "$" ?